# Problem with Magento category description! please help

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.0.1, category-products, locations

My category description above (before the goods).
I wish to change the location of the category description. This should be at the bottom (after the goods).
I am using magento commerce 1.9

Comment: `this answer also did not work for me can somebody just give the right answer please!!` put as comment behalf of Be media
`

Answer (score 1):

Copy template/catalog/category/view.phtml to your template and move this part of the code:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

just below:

```
<?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
```

Thus:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>

<?php elseif($this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```